# dynamically render div based on selectbox input rails 5 and select.js plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, selectize.js

I have a Rails 5, ruby 2.4.0, bootstrap 4 alpha 6 app using the selectize.js plugin.

What I am trying to do is display device info based on the selected item in the select box.

Currently, When the page loads the div is hidden as it should be and the select box is displayed (as it should be) but when I select anything other than the first select option, it wont change the device in the div.

I am a java / ajax noob and am lost for a solution. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

> **my select-box:**

```
  <select class="form-control div-toggle" id="select-device" data-target=".device-names">
    <option>Select Device</option>
    <% @devices.each do |device| %>
      <option value="<%= device.id %>" show=".<%= device.device_name %>"> <%= device.device_name.titleize %></option>
    <% end %>
  </select>
```

> **My Div to be rendered and displayed for each device when its selected:**

```
<div class="container device-names">
  <% @devices.each do |device_div| %>
    <div class="<%= device_div.id %> invisible" id="result">
      <div class="phoneDetailsContainer">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <center><h5 class="deviceHeader"><%= device_div.manufacturer.name.titleize %> | <%= device_div.device_name.upcase %></h5></center>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm-down"></div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4" id="deviceDivImageContainer">
            <center>
              <% if device_div.image.present? %>
                <%= image_tag device_div.image_url(:thumb), :class => "deviceImage" %>
              <% else %>

              <% end %>
            </center>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm-down"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4"></div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
            <center>
              <span class="proceedDisclaimer">By clicking this button you agree that this is the device in your possession</span>
              <%= link_to "Proceed to Carrier Selection", manufacturer_device_path(@manufacturer, device_div), class: 'btn btn-outline-primary proceedButton', :id => "proceed" %>
            </center>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

> **my javaScript to call the div when the item is selected:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ready = function () {
    // add code here
      $('#result').hide();

      $('#select-device').selectize({

      });

      $('#select-device').change(function(){

        $('#result').show().removeClass('invisible')
      });
    //end code here
  }

  $(document).ready(ready);
  $(document).on('page:load', ready);
  $(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready);
</script>
```

Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated! please let me know if further info is required!

Comment: I am not a ruby guru but no two html elements can have same ids. That is the biggest reason why your script is not working as expected.

Comment: same result even after changing it up

Answer (score 0):

A fair warning. I am NOT much knowledgeable on ruby and thus my answer might be bit buggy on ruby side.

### HTML

```
    <div class="container device-names">
       <% @devices.each do |device_div| %>
        <!-- first id change -->
        <div class="invisible" id="result<%= device_div.id %> ">
          <div class="phoneDetailsContainer">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <center><h5 class="deviceHeader"><%= device_div.manufacturer.name.titleize %> | <%= device_div.device_name.upcase %></h5></center>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm-down"></div>
              <!-- second id change -->
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4" id="deviceDivImageContainer<%= device_div.id %> ">
                <center>
                  <% if device_div.image.present? %>
                    <%= image_tag device_div.image_url(:thumb), :class => "deviceImage" %>
                  <% else %>

                  <% end %>
                </center>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm-down"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4"></div>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                <center>
                  <span class="proceedDisclaimer">By clicking this button you agree that this is the device in your possession</span>
                  <!-- third id change. Not knowing ruby i cannot help here -->
                  <%= link_to "Proceed to Carrier Selection", manufacturer_device_path(@manufacturer, device_div), class: 'btn btn-outline-primary proceedButton', :id => "proceed" %>
                </center>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
```

### Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        //result.hide is not wanted as elements are already having class invisible
          //Assuming that the dropdown values have same values as element ids
          $('#select-device').change(function(){
            $('#'+$('#select-device').val()).removeClass('invisible')
          });
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your jQuery selector for $('#result') is going to return an array of all the elements which match your selector. You want to find the one which has the class of the id of the item. You can pass the target into the function like this

```
  $('#select-device').change(function(e){
     id = $(e.target).val()
     $('.' + id).removeClass('hidden')
  }
```